# Add multiple tracking numbers to an amazon order using MWS API

Tags: amazon-mws

I am trying to upload multiple tracking numbers to an Amazon order using MWS API in PHP but don't know what would be the XML request for this. Here is the XML I am using which ends up uploading the last tracking number.

```
$feed = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>XXX</MerchantIdentifier>
        </Header>
        <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
        <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
            <AmazonOrderID>$orderId</AmazonOrderID>
            <FulfillmentDate>$FulfillmentDate</FulfillmentDate>
            <FulfillmentData>
                <CarrierCode>$carrierCode</CarrierCode>
                <ShipperTrackingNumber>'1Z7X887R0370783509'</ShipperTrackingNumber>
            </FulfillmentData>
            <Item>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </Item>

        </OrderFulfillment>
        </Message>
        <MessageID>2</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
            <AmazonOrderID>$orderId</AmazonOrderID>
            <FulfillmentDate>$FulfillmentDate</FulfillmentDate>
            <FulfillmentData>
                <CarrierCode>$carrierCode</CarrierCode>
                <ShipperTrackingNumber>'1Z7X887R0075127492'</ShipperTrackingNumber>
            </FulfillmentData>
            <Item>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </Item>
        </OrderFulfillment>
        </Message>
        <MessageID>3</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
            <AmazonOrderID>$orderId</AmazonOrderID>
            <FulfillmentDate>$FulfillmentDate</FulfillmentDate>
            <FulfillmentData>
                <CarrierCode>$carrierCode</CarrierCode>
                <ShipperTrackingNumber>'1Z7X887R0375972085'</ShipperTrackingNumber>
            </FulfillmentData>
            <Item>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
           </Item>

        </OrderFulfillment>
        </Message>
    </AmazonEnvelope>
EOD;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following XML. Hope it helps.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>     
   <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>      
   <MerchantIdentifier>My Store</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>  
<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
<Message>     
   <MessageID>1</MessageID>     
   <OrderFulfillment>         
   <MerchantOrderID>1234567</MerchantOrderID>        
   <MerchantFulfillmentID>1234567</MerchantFulfillmentID>         
   <FulfillmentDate>2002-05-01T15:36:33-08:00</FulfillmentDate>         
   <FulfillmentData>            
      <CarrierCode>UPS</CarrierCode>            
      <ShippingMethod>Second Day</ShippingMethod>             
      <ShipperTrackingNumber>1Z7X887R0075127492</ShipperTrackingNumber>        
   </FulfillmentData>          
   <Item>            
      <MerchantOrderItemID>11</MerchantOrderItemID>              
      <MerchantFulfillmentItemID>11</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>            
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>         
   </Item>     
   </OrderFulfillment>
</Message>
<Message>     
   <MessageID>2</MessageID>     
   <OrderFulfillment>         
   <MerchantOrderID>1234567</MerchantOrderID>        
   <MerchantFulfillmentID>1234567</MerchantFulfillmentID>         
   <FulfillmentDate>2002-05-01T15:36:33-08:00</FulfillmentDate>         
   <FulfillmentData>            
      <CarrierCode>UPS</CarrierCode>            
      <ShippingMethod>Second Day</ShippingMethod>             
      <ShipperTrackingNumber>1Z7X887R0075127492</ShipperTrackingNumber>        
   </FulfillmentData>          
   <Item>            
      <MerchantOrderItemID>22</MerchantOrderItemID>              
      <MerchantFulfillmentItemID>22</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>            
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>         
   </Item>     
   </OrderFulfillment>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

For more information about XSD, you can refer to [Amazon order Fulfilment XSD](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/200387170)

Comment: Sorry, I got busy in another project for some days. I tried this XML but it doesn't seems to work. The system doesn't returns any error too, so you never get to know where you are wrong.

Comment: I am not able to find the MerchantOrderItemID and MerchantFulfillmentItemID in my account. Any idea where do we get that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not properly opening your messages.

Try this:

```
</Message>
  Add this -->  <Message>
        <MessageID>2</MessageID>    

 </Message>
Add this -->  <Message>
        <MessageID>3</MessageID>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but in case anyone else is looking and can't get the XML to work, I did ultimately find the answer for myself, which was to submit the feed as a flat file instead of XML. My solution was in C# and not PHP, but basically the FeedType has to be set to  "*POST_FLAT_FILE_FULFILLMENT_DATA*"

```
  request.FeedType = "_POST_FLAT_FILE_FULFILLMENT_DATA_";
```

instead of "*POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA*" and then submit a tab-delimited text file in the format defined here (from their European site, but I use this in the United States marketplace):

https://sellercentral-europe.amazon.com/gp/help/external/help.html?itemID=13491

I tried repeatedly to get the XML to work with a few different variations and simply could not make it work. Amazon's documentation on this is terrible and doesn't describe how to format the XML for multiple tracking numbers. When I switched to the flat file feed, it worked right away. If anyone has had any luck with the XML version, I would be interested in seeing that. I had an open case with Amazon for quite a while trying to get this information from them and they kept insisting that I was asking them to write my code for me when really I just wanted guidance on how to format the XML correctly for their system. I suspect that there is no way to get two tracking numbers to work in and XML feed and that it only works with a flat file.